# Cisco anyconnect keeps disconnecting and reconnecting

Tags: vpn, cisco-vpn-client

For some reason every few minutes Cisco anyconnect VPN client keeps disconnecting and reconnecting.

Example log:

```
  4:28:43 PM    Connected to myaccess.oraclevpn.com.
     4:34:10 PM    Reconnecting to myaccess.oraclevpn.com...
     4:34:10 PM    Establishing VPN - Examining system...
     4:34:10 PM    Establishing VPN - Activating VPN adapter...
     4:34:10 PM    Establishing VPN - Configuring system...
     4:34:10 PM    Establishing VPN...
     4:34:10 PM    Connected to myaccess.oraclevpn.com.
     4:35:30 PM    Reconnecting to myaccess.oraclevpn.com...
     4:35:30 PM    Establishing VPN - Examining system...
     4:35:30 PM    Establishing VPN - Activating VPN adapter...
     4:35:30 PM    Establishing VPN - Configuring system...
     4:35:30 PM    Establishing VPN...
     4:35:30 PM    Connected to myaccess.oraclevpn.com.
     4:49:35 PM    Reconnecting to myaccess.oraclevpn.com...
     4:49:36 PM    Establishing VPN - Examining system...
     4:49:36 PM    Establishing VPN - Activating VPN adapter...
     4:49:36 PM    Establishing VPN - Configuring system...
     4:49:36 PM    Establishing VPN...
     4:49:36 PM    Connected to myaccess.oraclevpn.com.
     5:19:20 PM    Reconnecting to myaccess.oraclevpn.com...
     5:19:20 PM    Establishing VPN - Examining system...
     5:19:20 PM    Establishing VPN - Activating VPN adapter...
     5:19:20 PM    Establishing VPN - Configuring system...
     5:19:20 PM    Establishing VPN...
     5:19:20 PM    Connected to myaccess.oraclevpn.com.
     5:21:46 PM    Reconnecting to myaccess.oraclevpn.com...
     5:21:46 PM    Establishing VPN - Examining system...
     5:21:46 PM    Establishing VPN - Activating VPN adapter...
     5:21:46 PM    Establishing VPN - Configuring system...
     5:21:46 PM    Establishing VPN...
     5:21:46 PM    Connected to myaccess.oraclevpn.com.
     5:27:31 PM    Reconnecting to myaccess.oraclevpn.com...
     5:27:31 PM    Establishing VPN - Examining system...
     5:27:31 PM    Establishing VPN - Activating VPN adapter...
     5:27:31 PM    Establishing VPN - Configuring system...
     5:27:31 PM    Establishing VPN...
```

I am on latest 4.6.01103

Comment: Reconnects could happen for many reasons. For example, when a new n/w interface comes up or when OS reports interface configuration change to AnyConnect etc., Are you seeing this issue on Windows 10 ? If yes, does your device have capability to use cellular network ?

Comment: This still happens to me in 2024. And I do not find a way to get my good internet back, which I had for long before this problem came up.

Comment: I have this bad internet only in one WLAN of two WLANs at home. The other one works fine, and also USB-Tethering from my mobile phone works fine. Therefore, I checked the router of the bad WLAN and restarted it. After this, the laggy internet was still there. Now in a public internet, the internet or AnyConnect reconnects the same way in the first two minutes (8 reconnect messages), but afterwards, it runs without reconnects. Perhaps, what is happening in those first two minutes happens all over again in the other WLAN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me what solved this is to work only on wifi or only on wired ethernet connection (I disabled the wifi adapter (in Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Network Connections in win10)

Now everything is stable!

Comment: You saved my day, i was a step closer to burn the network!

Comment: I didn't succeed with this option. I am connected to wifi and have disabled wired connection. However, every other minute VPN gets disconnected. Are there some other thoughts?

Comment: don't know what if wlan or vEthernet deactivation @joeBun helped..but it's stable now !

Answer (score 3):

I know this thread is old but I just ran into this problem (it would reconnect at least several times/hour - sometimes several times within a 60 second span). The above two solutions didn't work for me (disabling unused network connections, shutting down hyper-v machine) but what DID work for me was disabling IPV-6 under network connections:

Open up network connections, right click on wi-fi or ethernet, go to properties and uncheck the box corresponding to Internet Protocol Version 6.

I thought I saw that suggestion in this thread, but I can't find it anymore. Good luck!

Comment: Can anyone leave some screenshots of this? I do not find it on Windows 11.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and inspired by thedrs answer, I disabled all network adapters I didn't need for the VPN connection.

It turned out that the **Hyper-V machine** (and the corresponding virtual Ethernet adapter) I had running were causing it. After shutting down the virtual machine, no more reconnects occurred.

Comment: Of course, not Hyper-V is the problem, because other Networking SW like CheckPoint or even the free OpenVPN SW works stable with it. **It's Cisco who does not do it's homework and do not integrate it's "tools" into Windows 10 as it should be.**

Comment: It worked for me but disabling Hyper V in windows features and restarting my machine

Answer (score 0):

##### Wait this out; give it roughly 2 weeks

This still happens in 2024.

Before you go on reading: this problem should vanish into thin air, as other people found it as well. For me, it took perhaps two days until the many reconnections were gone. Then they came back after some more days up to the point that I could not work well enough on that WLAN anymore, while another WLAN worked all the time. After 13 days from the first peak, my Anyconnect VPN Laptop could not connect to the WLAN anymore even though the other devices could. Thus, there was a change somehow, which is something good as such. Some hours later, I restarted the router and could connect again. And since then, the WLAN works as it should.

If you are stuck: you might try many restarts of the router, perhaps 10 in one day. And since it must be a router problem, you can also try it with another router. The flickering internet cannot come from the provider since I could move my laptop to another router of the same provider contract, and that router worked all the time.

##### Background

I did not find a way to get my good internet back, which I had before this problem came up. But I also did not change anything of the other answers or fixes from the net that would need Admin rights.

I had this bad internet only in one WLAN of two WLANs at home:

[image]

It seemed to be blocked since I also cannot browse the internet while being disconnected:

[image]

The other WLAN worked fine, and also USB-Tethering from my mobile phone on a mobile provider worked fine. Therefore, I checked the router of the bad WLAN and restarted it. After this, the laggy internet was still there. In a public internet, the internet or AnyConnect reconnects the same way in the first two minutes (8 reconnect messages), but afterwards, it runs without reconnections. Perhaps, what is happening in those first two minutes happens all over again in the other WLAN?

I found:

- [Fix Traffic Flow Disruptions Caused by
  AnyConnect Reconnections](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/security/anyconnect-secure-mobility-client/116881-technote-anyconnect-00.pdf) of 2022
- Many other Threads on Cisco like [Cisco AnyConnect disconnects every 5 minutes then reconnects continuously on Ubuntu 20.04](https://community.cisco.com/t5/vpn/cisco-anyconnect-disconnects-every-5-minutes-then-reconnects/td-p/4400917)

But as other people also found, the problem goes away without doing anything. It took roughly 11 days until I could work flawlessly again, but only after the router decided to stop working for my laptop (while the rest worked as always):

[image]

*(No connection possible with this network)*

So that I restarted it again some hours later.

##### DART bundle from AnyConnect Diagnostics Tool

Get the DART logs from the Diagnostics tool of AnyConnect

[image]

[image]

The zip file that is made has the timestamp in the filename and gives you the whole bundle of any Internet and computer logs you can think of. It has so many entries that you can even see when you changed your power cable or when the kernel woke up from standby.

See [How to collect the DART bundle for Anyconnect](https://community.cisco.com/t5/security-knowledge-base/how-to-collect-the-dart-bundle-for-anyconnect/ta-p/3156025).

Answer (score -2):

There are 3 parties involved in this problem. Cisco, your IT dept, and ISP. They can fix it by either changing group policy and moving the port, etc. Apparently, your ISP is limiting and disconnecting people using VPN to watch overseas TV. That's why your company VPN keeps reconnecting. But when you call them, they will point to the other two parties. So the ONLY and easiest way for you to do YOURSELF is to disable all other connections, including Bluetooth, Virtual Machine, Wired (if you're on wireless). And for the remaining wireless AND AnyConnect connection, UNCHECK IP6 from the network properties! Easy fix by yourself and work and uptime 100% for those WFH and Covid Lockdown folks.